# Submit plunker code embeded programmatically

Tags: javascript, iframe, plunker

I would like to know if is possible to have an HTML page with an iframe with [plunker](https://plnkr.co/) embededed and an external button that will take the `plunker` code and submit it to my server once the user clicks submit ?

Comment: There would be CORS issue.

Comment: @Jai Isn't there any kind of API from plunker that would allow me to do it ?
Another way, I am building an API in angularJS that people would use as an embedded IDE and I would like to use something like plunker that they will be able to submit their code for analysis. Probably this API will need to use some code that will download the zip. and from POST it to my website by some kind of login.

Comment: @Tito, since Plunker's embed is hosted at https://embed.plnkr.co (a different host from the site embedding the iframe), you will be unable to reach into the iframe.

There is *currently* no API for an embedder to talk to the embed editor but I'm open to considering this for the right use case.

Comment: Hello @filearts, my idea is to have an embedded editor for my e-learning website, where advanced users (developers) can create something I called apps (Is a set of HTML, CSS3 and javaScript) that will reference my API. I already tried the other tools on the market, but yours seems that is much closer to what I want to achieve :) It would be a pleasure for me to explain you better how I want to do it in more details via email or other kind of communication if you are open for that. :)

Comment: It will work like an embedded IDE where people can submit their code and we will analyze if this app will be published or not.

Comment: @Tito please reach out to me at my username, on gmail.

Comment: @filearts Hello Geoffrey, I made a more elaborated question on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51389437/send-and-get-data-from-code-editor-like-plunker-embedded . Sorry to come back to this topic, but now I have a project to show. Are you still using Google Hangouts? I have sent you a message in there.